# How to use mencoder to speed up video?

Tags: video, conversion, debian, encoding, mencoder

There's a webcam streaming WMV video that I can play/record with mplayer/mencoder (Debian Lenny including Debian-multimedia) just fine.

I'd like to capture the video such that, when played back, it's faster (so say 100s of real time zooms past in every 1s of video).

The "frameskip" filter seems like it ought to do this, but when I try e.g

```
mencoder -o output.avi -ofps 25 -vf framestep=100 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:... <mms source URL>
```

what I actually get is something which plays for the same length of time as it's allowed to capture for, but which only updates the displayed image every 4 seconds.

Is there any way mencoder can be persuaded to do what I want ?

(By the way, ideally I'd like to *average* the frames together to obtain motion-blur instead of just dropping/discarding most of them.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha: what I wanted was the `-speed` option.  Somehow missed it amongst all the other stuff in the manual.

Comment: A note of hindsight: `-speed` is unreliable. Its stability seems to rely on peculiarities of the A/V tracks and the host CPU resources, and I've never managed to get it to play very quickly at all. I don't know of a better option, but I wish there was one.