# How do I slow down a video generating new interpolated frames?

Tags: video, conversion, encoding, framerate

I've used [mencoder's speed parameter](https://superuser.com/questions/115527/how-to-use-mencoder-to-speed-up-video) to generate a video which is played at half the speed. This basically means halving the framerate of the video. But I'm interested in software that could convert a 30fps video to another 30fps video with half the frames interpolated, maybe using the motion information stored in the video stream *per se*. I think this is called intra-frame interpolation, but I haven't found anything practical other than research papers.

Any pointers to such software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is already answered at [Looking for temporal upsampling / motion interpolation software](https://superuser.com/questions/224095/looking-for-temporal-upsampling-motion-interpolation-software).